# Assert.AreEqual Statements not Successfully passing - Linq2Sql Converting

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

```
string dwQuery =
//                    @"SELECT par.[Package_Name] Parent_Package,  
//                    Count(chld.Package_Name) as NumberOfChildren
//                    FROM [SRS_Dim_Audit] par INNER JOIN SRS_Dim_Audit chld ON par.Audit_Key = chld.Parent_Audit_Key
//                    WHERE par.[Package_Name] NOT LIKE 'SQL Query Sample Data' AND 
//                    par.Processing_Successful = 1 AND chld.Processing_Successful = 1
//                    GROUP BY par.[Package_Name]";
```

The statement above is to test two Assert statements:

```
Assert.AreEqual("SRSMasterStage_To_DW", dResultsDw.Rows[iRow][0].ToString());
Assert.AreEqual("10", dResultsDw.Rows[iRow][1].ToString());
```

---

I have written:

```
Assert.AreEqual("SRSMasterStage_To_DW", auditRecords.FirstOrDefault().Parent_Package);
Assert.AreEqual("10", auditRecords.FirstOrDefault().NumberOfChildren);
```

---

When I run it I recieve an error that states:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
```

---

How do I reference what it is asking?!

I know that FirstOrDefault is returning a Null but thats because the row with "'SQL Query Sample Data'", does not have an Audit_Key, it just shows Null.

Any solutions?
What can be used inplace of FirstOrDefault? How would you go about this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `.FirstOrDefault` returns `null`, then accessing any property on the object such as `Parent_Package` or `NumberOfChildren` will produce that error.

During testing, you should be in control of the environment. If you know that you're going to receive a `null`, then the only check you should be doing is something like `Assert.IsNull(auditRecords)`.

If you know you're going to get one or more rows back, then the above `Assert` statements would be fine.

---

To test for null, try something like this (untested):

```
Assert.IsNull(auditRecords.FirstOrDefault());
```

The `Default` for most objects is null. *(Here's a reference for the [default values for primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)*.

Comment: what if the assert.isnull fails?

Comment: is there any way you could provide to me the converted version of the two assert.areequal statements?

Comment: helped a little bit, but i have been stuck on these two assert statements since noon

Comment: on the error that I made this question about.."Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------